# Periodic Tasks with Celery and Django

Tags: python, django, celery, periodic-task

I'm having troubles getting a periodic tasks to run with Celery 3.1.8, Django 1.6.1, and RabbitMQ. I'm a bit confused with the current documentation as I understand that django-celery is not needed anymore to get Celery running with Django. I have a feeling that I'm not running the worker correctly, but after searching for a solution on SO and googling, I'm in need of help. Could anyone point me in the right direction with this?

settings.py (not sure if I need this since I have a @periodic_task decorator on my task)

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.send_test_email',
        'schedule': datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
    },
}
```

My app (celery.py)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

app = Celery('app',
             broker='amqp://',
             backend='amqp://',
             include=['app.tasks'])


app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
    CELERY_TIMEZONE='Europe/Oslo',
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Periodic task (tasks.py)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery.task import periodic_task
import datetime

@periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))
def send_test_email():
    print "This is a periodic task from celery"
```

On the command line, I'm executing the worker:

```
celery worker -A app -l info
celery beat
```

Comment: So after tinkering around more, I was able to get it working. The problem was how I was executing the worker. This did the trick:    **celery -A app beat**

Comment: You should add that as an answer instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Some other solution would be to use the `@periodic_task` [celery decorator](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.1-archived/reference/celery.decorators.html)

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=0, hour=1))
def my_task():
    print 'my_task'
```